# Cómo mandar los valores de los input disabled en el submit

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Tengo un formulario con algunos input disabled *(¿Por qué? -> lo explico abajo)*
y quiero que se los valores se envíen en el el submint.

**Por qué son disabled:**
Por que sus valores se calculan en función del resto de input y no los he puesto como readonly por que no quiero que al pulsar la tecla de tabulación el foco pase por ellos.

Estoy usuando jQuery y javascrip.

Comment: Si usas javascript (lo has puesto como etiqueta) esto no afectará para nada el comportamiento, puedes obtener el valor de los input igualmente

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si lo que quieres es que no sean enfocados con navegación de teclado usa tabindex="-1"

```
<input tabindex="-1" value="b">
```

Comment: Juraría que lo había probado esto en w3chool y no me había funcionado, pero lo he vuelto a probar y tienes razón.
sigo teniendo un problema, me exigen que tampoco pueda hacer click en el, quiero decir, no puede tener nunca el foco.

Comment: En ese caso, esto podría servirte:
`<input value="b" tabindex="-1" onfocus="this.blur()">`

Answer (score 1):

Puedes crear un ajax en el cual le mandes los parámetros que quieras desde tu **controlador** a través del **url** del ajax.

Ejemplo:

```
$(".submit").click(function(){
        if(!validar("fomrularioX")){
            $(".div_boton").html('<div class="progress progress-striped active">\n\
                    <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: 100%"></div>\n\
            </div>');
            var datos = creaObjeto("formularioX");
            datos.variable= $('input:radio[name=var]:checked').val();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                data: datos,
                url: "<?=base_url("index.php/TUREDIRECCION/AL/CONTROLADOR")?>",
                success: function(data){
                    //Aquí llamas a tu Submit sea disable o enable.
                    });    
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Ya en tu controlador creas una función de acuerdo a lo que quieres que haga:

```
public function realizarSubmit{
         ///Código
```

}

Ya es tu decisión si lo mandas por **.click, ready etc** el ajax.
Espero que te sirva. Suerte!

Comment: El OP No ha especificado si usa php, ni jQuery (cierto que está en la etiqueta pero no lo muestra en ninguna parte)...

Comment: Cierto, deberi haber dicho que si que utilizo jQuery.
Le veo un problema a esta solucion... corregirme si me equivoco.
al hacer el submit por ajax, perdere el control de los (require, mas, min ... de los input) y tendria que hacer todo ese control a mano .¿Me equivoco?

Comment: Leí que había una etiqueta Javascript, JQuery, por ende mi respuesta.

Debería funcionarte sin necesidad de hacer todo a mano como dices, pero otra alternativa si no funcionara (debería de funcionarte el max y min), sería que realizaras una validación por el controlador. :)

Answer (score 0):

Si gustas también puedes agregar el input en un div y al div ponerle un display="none"; ,

haciendo esto ocultaras el input y podrás enviar los datos sin ningún problema con JavaScript o directamente con php